# Use precise mapping annotation, i.e. '@GetMapping', '@PostMapping', etc

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, request-mapping, spring-framework-beans

`Replace @RequestMapping with specific @GetMapping, @PostMapping etc.`

I'm trying to show the jsp page in the browser. So I used @RequestMapping. But it shows warning like `Use precise mapping annotation, i.e. '@GetMapping', '@PostMapping', etc.`

```
public class LocationControler 
{
    @RequestMapping("/showCreate")
    public String showCreate()
    {
        return "CreateLocation";
    }
}
```

CreateLocation will display the jsp file CreateLocation.jsp.

In application.properties I have set like this

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsps/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

I tried with `@PostMapping`
In browser I'm getting this error.
`There was an unexpected error (type=Method Not Allowed, status=405).`

For this whic method should I use?.

```
@GetMapping - shortcut for @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
@PostMapping - shortcut for @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
@PutMapping - shortcut for @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT)
@DeleteMapping - shortcut for @RequestMapping(method =RequestMethod.DELETE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you are using specific http method, go with @GetMapping, which will be used by default by your browser. I do recommend to read up about various http methods and their usage though.

Comment: @GetMapping is working. I wonder how? Get will get the respective value right? How comes the jsp page. I'm bit confused with Restful webservice.

Answer (score 0):

When you use **@PostMapping**，program will get error，

so, you can use **@GetMapping**, or  **@RequestMapping(path = "/showCreate")**， and don't take notice of warning